# [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@errno'

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, odbc

We have a classic asp page interacting with SQL Server 2000 Using ODBC SQL Server Driver. DB team moved this instance to SQL Server 2014. Now we have a procedure which is not using `RAISEERROR` @error syntax but still in the same procedure we get the below error:

> Error Number = (-2147217900)
>   Error Description: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@errno'.
>   Error Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

I checked in .asp code @errno is not being used. It is just a simple INSERT statement.

Could anybody help me know what the error is. The application is hosted on a Windows 2003 Machine. Should I update the ODBC Driver so it talks to SQL Server 2014 correctly. Is that an option?

When I googled for the error number I did not get exact match, but for some other error no the resolution was to set Compatibility Mode to 80. Will this eliminate the error?

ASP CODE:

```vb
sub subPutValueIntoReport_Table (sBenefit, sCategory, sFiscal, sReport, sLine, fAmt, sCalendar)
    dim sProc, oRS
    sProc = "spReport_Table 'SELECT_AMOUNT'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sBenefit & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sCategory & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sFiscal & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sReport & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sLine & "'"
    dbExecuteSqlRS oRS, sProc

    'If the record does not exist, insert the record, else update the record
    if oRS.bof and oRS.eof then
        sProc = "spReport_Table 'INSERT'"
    else
        if "1" & oRS(0) & "1" = "11" then
            sProc = "spReport_Table 'INSERT'"
        else
            sProc = "spReport_Table 'UPDATE'"
        end if
    end if

    oRS.close
    set oRS = nothing
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sBenefit & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sCategory & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sFiscal & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sReport & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sLine & "'"
    sProc = sProc & "," & fAmt
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & sCalendar & "'"
    sProc = sProc & ", '" & session("userid") & "'"

    if session("debug") then Response.Write "<br>" & sProc & "<br>"

    dbExecuteSql sProc
end sub
```

SP I cannot provide full SP details will remove some important details like table names and comments:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE spReport_Table  
 @query_type varchar(20),  
 @benefit_code varchar(4),  
 @category_code varchar(4),  
 @fiscal_period char(6),  
 @report_name varchar(40),  
 @line_desc varchar(40),  
 @line_amt decimal (20, 2) = 0,  
 @cal_period varchar(6) = '000000',  
 @uid varchar(20) = 'xProc'  

AS  

/*-- define variables */  
DECLARE @sSql AS NVARCHAR(2000)  

IF UPPER(@query_type) = 'SELECT_AMOUNT'  
 BEGIN  
  SET @sSql = "SELECT sum(Line_Amt) "  
  SET @sSql = @sSql + "FROM table "  
  SET @sSql = @sSql + "WHERE column_name1 in (" + @benefit_code  + ") "  
  SET @sSql = @sSql + "AND column_name2 = '" + @category_code + "' "  
  SET @sSql = @sSql + "AND column_name3 = '" + @fiscal_period + "' "  
  SET @sSql = @sSql + "AND column_name4 = '" + @report_name + "' "  
  SET @sSql = @sSql + "AND column_name5 = '" + @line_desc + "' "  

  EXEC  sp_executesql @sSql  
 END  

ELSE IF UPPER(@query_type) ='INSERT'  
 INSERT INTO Table (column_names)   
 VALUES (values)  

ELSE IF UPPER(@query_type) ='UPDATE'  
 UPDATE Table  
 SET colum_names=values  

ELSE IF UPPER(@query_type) ='DELETE'  
 DELETE FROM Table   
 WHERE Condition
```

Comment: Can you show your code (ASP, SQL query)?

Comment: Be aware that Microsoft changed the syntax of the RaiseError function, it did not require parentheses in old versions, but it is required from version 2012, check if this might be causing the error.

Comment: @Gedeon that is the confusion here. Our SP is not even using RAISEERROR. I will update my question with code and sp

Comment: Try running the output from the debug in SSMS, does it still error?

Comment: Also the way you build the query for `sp_executesql` means you are leaving yourselves open to SQL Injection. You can pass defined parameters into `sp_executesql` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Other question would be, are you positive it is this particular ASP code that is triggering the error?

Comment: @Larnu I'm pretty sure the OP has said they moved the DB instance to SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @Lankymart Clearly it's too early. #need more coffee. :)

Comment: You probably have one or more triggers on the table. In the trigger, the RAISEERROR syntax will require parenthesis.

Comment: @nicoboey I need to check that. Thanks.

Comment: @nicoboey You were right. The raiseerror was used in a trigger. After updating all the triggers with modified syntax everything is back to normal. Thanks 